# Computer vision, image processing software algorithms for identification, synonym, segregation of english & american words & terms images

Tags: word-usage, american-english, terminology, british-english, speech

https://www.google.com/search?q=words+difference+between+american+and+british+english&oq=Words+difference+between+american+eng&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30i457.20248j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Are there computer vision & image processing software algorithms which will recognise, detect and segregate british english & american english terms, words, synonyms?

Input dataset : Individual images of english terms & words.

Output : Identify the equivalent american word or term, synonym & vice versa.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane that this is off topic but I would also point out that any such software is likely to have quite a high error rate. It might give the more obvious ones like "baby carriage" for "pram" and give "hood" for "bonnet" in terms of cars but it would probably also convert "Lady's bonnet" to "Lady's hood" as well which would not be correct since a bonnet and a hood are two different things in clothing. It might also tell Americans to use "Scotch Hood" chillies in cookery which would leave them scratching their heads.